# My question is about Appending excel data from active workbook to the bottom of a master file VBA Code Help Request

Tags: vba, append

I am trying to append the data in MaxWB to the bottom of the data in MasterWB.

I can copy the date, open the next file, but my code has an error when I try to find the last row and add a row or offset by 1 by one row.

I believe my paste special also has an error, but I can get past the offset to test.

I am very new to VBA, but like it!
Here is my Code:

```
Sub Append()

Dim MaxWB As Workbook
Dim MasterWB As Workbook
Dim path As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Rng As Range

    Set MaxWB = ActiveWorkbook

    Sheets("Final Export FTP").Select
    Range("A1:E1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy

    Set MasterWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ka20839\Desktop\Database\336116001.csv")

    Set MasterWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("ONParamfile").Select

    Range("A1").Select

With Worksheets("ONParamfile")

    Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = .Range("A" & Lastrow)

End With

'destCell appends I tried and failed to figure out
'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select.Offset (1) '.Select


    ' paste throwing an error too
   ' .Range("A" & Lastrow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'save master file
    MasterWB.Close SaveChanges:=True


End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What error message do you receive and on what line?

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid selecting objects:

```
Sub Append()

    Dim wkbSource As Workbook, wkbTarget As Workbook
    Dim lngLastRowSource As Long, lngLastRowTarget As Long


    Set wkbSource = ActiveWorkbook

    With Worksheets("Final Export FTP")
        lngLastRowSource = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With


    Set wkbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ka20839\Desktop\Database\336116001.csv")

    With Worksheets("ONParamfile")
        lngLastRowTarget = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With


    wkbSource.Worksheets("Final Export FTP").Range("A1:E" & lngLastRowSource).Copy _
        wkbTarget.Worksheets("ONParamfile").Range("A" & lngLastRowTarget)

End Sub
```